# Snowflake Scripting in SQL - how to iterate over the results of a SHOW command?

Tags: sql, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm checking out the new SQL Snowflake Scripting (in preview), and I can't figure out how to iterate over the results of a `SHOW` command — especially as some columns are lower cased.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/
- https://hoffa.medium.com/sql-scripting-live-in-snowflake-288ef8c272fa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this example as a template to iterate over results of `SHOW`:

```
declare
  res RESULTSET default (show warehouses);
  vw_cursor CURSOR for res;
  vw_table RESULTSET ;
begin
  for vw in vw_cursor do
    vw_table := (execute immediate 'show parameters like ' || '''STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS''' || ' in warehouse ' || vw."name");
    return TABLE(vw_table) ;
  end for;
end;
```

First, note that you can get the `resultset` from `show` in the `declare` part - that makes life easy.

Then you can have a cursor to go over each row with `for vw in vw_cursor do`.

Then you can `execute immediate` other queries, but make sure to quote with `"` to get the lower-cased columns like in `vw."name"`.

Comment: A deleted comment asked for creating a table in memory, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231620/sql-snowflake-scripting-how-can-i-return-a-table-created-in-memory-while-loopi